how to chain two nexflow script where output from the first goes input to the second
So i have so far two nextflow script first one is parse_annotation.nf which generates a .csv file then that goes as input for sample_parse.nf. Now so far i have figured out from examples how to run as standalone workflow.
Now my goal is put them together such that
this runs parse_annotation.nf first and then subsequently its output will be taken as input for sample_parse.nf which will generate output which i have tested the python script it works fine.
parse_annotation.nf
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

// Check if files exist
println "Checking file existence..."
println "parse_annotation.py exists: ${file('parse_annotation.py').exists()}"
println "sample_annot.txt exists: ${file('sample_annot.txt').exists()}"

// Print current working directory
println "Current working directory: ${System.getenv('PWD')}"

// Define the input annotation file channel
annotation_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.annotation_file)

// Define the process that runs the parse_annotation.py script
process parse_annotation {
    input:
        path annotation_file

    output:
        path "sample.csv"

    script:
        """
        python3 /home/krushna/temp/parse_annotation.py -f $annotation_file > sample_output.txt 2>&1
        """
}

// Run the process
workflow {
    parse_annotation(annotation_ch)
}


sample_parse.nf
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

// Define input file parameters
params.csv_file = null
params.annot_file = null

// Check if files exist
println "Checking file existence..."
println "sample_parse.py exists: ${file('sample_parse.py').exists()}"
println "CSV file exists: ${file(params.csv_file).exists()}"
println "Annotation file exists: ${file(params.annot_file).exists()}"

// Define the input file channels
csv_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.csv_file)
annot_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.annot_file)

// Combine the input file channels
input_files = csv_ch.combine(annot_ch)

// Define the process that runs the sample_parse.py script
process parse_sample {
    input:
    tuple path(csv_file), path(annot_file)

    output:
    path "parsed_output_dir"

    script:
    """
    mkdir parsed_output_dir
    python3 /home/krushna/temp/sample_parse.py $csv_file $annot_file
    mv *.samplesheet.csv *.info.txt parsed_output_dir/
    """
}

// Run the process
workflow {
    parse_sample(input_files)
}

Any template example with DSL-2 format would be really helpful and appreciated

Looks like you simply need a third nf file / workflow that would use those processes you describe. Assuming that all your files are located in the same folder:
main.nf:
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
include { parse_annotation } from "./parse_annotation.nf"
include { sample_parse } from "./sample_parse.nf"

workflow {
    annotation_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.annotation_file)
    csv_ch = parse_annotation(annotation_ch)
    parse_input = csv_ch.combine(annot_ch)
    sample_parse(parse_input)
}

Now as you can see this does not take in consideration the code in each process file that already loads in the inputs for  each individual process's file anonymous workflow. That may cause issues. Perhaps you simply want to remove that code all together if it was there just to demo that each process works individually. Otherwise is possible that you could keep that code and those workflows but moving all the code inside the corresponding workflow { ... } block so that only gets executed if you run the individual process .nf file directly.
For example parse_annotation.nf would look like this:
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

process parse_annotation { 
   ...
}

workflow {
   println "Checking file existence..."
   ...
   annotation_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.annotation_file)
   parse_annotation(annotation_ch)
}

}

therwise is possible that you could keep that code and those workflows but moving all the code inside the corresponding workflow { ... } block so that only gets executed if you run the individual process .nf file directly.  this can you explain bit more pretty dumb question though yet i can't  wrap my head around

@PesKchan I would need to try it myself but when you 'include' a nf from another nf to reuse the processes or workflows defined there is possible that the code in that file that is not enclosed in either process or a workflow gets executed. I'm not certain of this but regardless is kind bad practice to have executing code outside workflow; function definitions, imports etc are fine but not "main" code lines, that should be inside the workflow block.

okay...i will also try to do it if i can by reading examples
